# converting list<string> to IEnumerable<guid> inside an argument

Tags: c#

i have a function named  `GetContentPageToValueVo` which accepts `IEnumerable<Guid>` types , and here the locations and the services is of type `list<string>` ,  so how to convert this line in the argument to IEnumerable type , my locations list is coming from solr , and have valid guids in string format

```
Location = ScHelper.Instance().GetContentPageToValueVo(x.Locations),
                Service = ScHelper.Instance().GetContentPageToValueVo(x.Services)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use both the LINQ [`Select`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.select?view=netframework-4.8) method and [`Guid.Parse`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.guid.parse?view=netframework-4.8) to convert the `List<string>` to `IEnumerable<Guid>`.

The `Select` here will:

> Projects each element of a sequence into a new form by incorporating the element's index.

and the `Guid.Parse` will:

> Converts the string representation of a GUID to the equivalent Guid structure.

So your code will become:

```
Location = ScHelper.Instance().GetContentPageToValueVo(x.Locations.Select(Guid.Parse)),
Service = ScHelper.Instance().GetContentPageToValueVo(x.Services.Select(Guid.Parse))
```

In order to avoid `ArgumentNullException`, you could use that:

```
Guid y;

Location = ScHelper.Instance().GetContentPageToValueVo(x.Locations.Where(x=>!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(x) && Guid.TryParse(x,out y)).Select(Guid.Parse)),
Service = ScHelper.Instance().GetContentPageToValueVo(x.Services.Where(x=>!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(x) && Guid.TryParse(x,out y)).Select(Guid.Parse))
```

Comment: how can i put a null check and avoid the ArgumentnullExceptions here